# Can't rotate display in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, rotate

I'm running Windows 7 64-bit on a Dell Inspiron 1525 with an Intel 965 graphics chipset.  When I bring up the "screen resolution" settings, I can set up my primary and secondary display (the laptop + an LCD monitor) but there is no option for rotation.

I'm used to using this feature at work so I was surprised to see it missing.  I installed dell's latest drivers for this chipset (although they were not marked as Windows-7 or 64-bit) and no change.  Any idea what's going on here?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is not inbuilt to Windows but is entirely controlled and supported by your video card driver.  You can try, as a test, pressing CTRL-ALT-ARROWKEY (Right or Left), which is usually the default keyboard shortcuts for most video cards that support this feature.  But my guess would be that this isn't a feature supported by the video card driver supplied by Dell with your laptop.  What you can try, instead, is to download and install Intel's video card driver instead of the Dell driver.  I know Intel's drivers do include support for this feature on the 965 chipset.

Comment: Thanks for the tips BBlake.  Unfortunately I installed the Intel 965 mobile drivers, and still no dice.